# Assign variable to {% assign %}

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

Im trying to assign a 'var' in {%assign%} is it possible?

example:

```
var tag2 = $('#firstTag :selected').text();
if(tag2 != tag){
  $('#secondTag').val('');
  tag = tag2;
  {% assign firstTag = tag %}
}
```

The {%assign firstTag = tag %} obiviously doesn't work because it doesn't know im refering to the 'var tag'

How can I make firstTag equal to tag?

Answer (score 2):

No. It looks like you are trying to run javascript and have it affect .liquid.

For Shopify liquid is a server side language and javascript is a client side language. Once the client has your code there's nothing you can do with liquid.

Comment: D you know how can I get and use the slected value of a drop-down list using .liquid?

Comment: You can construct a URL for a specific Shopify object and change your page. So for a tag look at how a tag filter alters the URL and you can build that in JavaScript and change the location.